# A Quicker Directory.GetFiles()

Tags: c#

When I run this function, it literally takes minutes sometimes to find only 10 or so files. What is the problem? I created this function:

```cs
public static List<string> FindFiles(string sFilename, string sDir, SearchOption soOption = SearchOption.AllDirectories)
{
    List<string> lFiles = new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles(sDir, sFilename, soOption));
    return lFiles;
}
```

Why is this so slow? Is there another way to accomplish the same thing (finding files in a directory)?

Comment: You can enumerate directory files using p/invoke, if code portability is not an issue for you. You can start with FindFirstFile: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/FindFirstFile.html
and MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @ZoranCausev That's already what `GetFiles` / `EnumerateFiles` does.

Comment: Don't think the code here is an issue, althuogh I would recommend using the answer of @MichaelBray (Directory.EnumerateFiles). What's the size of the directory your searching in? It could be your leaning against the limitations of Windows here. Another question: is it on your machine or a network drive? This also impacts the performance.

Comment: It's on my local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are .NET 4+, then you can try **[Directory.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.IO.DIRECTORY.ENUMERATEFILES%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true)** instead.  It will return faster, but I think the total time that your code runs will still be more or less the same.